# Can't create an instance of WWW:Mechanize::Firefox

Tags: perl, automated-tests, www-mechanize

I've just installed [`WWW:Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox), but when I tried to create an instance of this "class":

```
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: 
No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it. 
at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you post some code? Also, what happens if you telnet into localhost:4242

Comment: the code is too simple because the bug is at the beginning: use WWW:Mechanize::Firefox;  $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(); print "blabla"; but it wont ofcourse coz it  exits before :s

Comment: and sorry im not familiar with telnet and basically networking!!

Comment: Do you have Mozrepl plugin installed in Firefox?

Comment: thank u you were right i didnt have MozRepl and now it works :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must install [mozrepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/mozrepl/) and start it in the menu `Tools → MozRepl → Start`.

Comment: How do I find Tools->MozRepl in firefox? Searched the whole layout, nothing

Comment: @Grigor: Right click any toolbar in the new firefox(not a tab): and click menu bar to view the menu bar. The menu bar then appears then it is tools->mozrepl->Start

Answer (score 2):

In addition to installing and starting firefox/mozrepl, an actively refused connection is frequently the work of a FIREWALL, so you need to learn to work your local firewall to allow mozrepl to listen for connections from localhost