# How do I crawl through a welcome page with Perl LWP?

Tags: perl, cookies, lwp

I'm trying to crawl this page using Perl LWP:

http://livingsocial.com/cities/86/deals/138811-hour-long-photo-session-cd-and-more

I had code that used to be able to handle living social, but it seems to have stopped working. Basically the idea was to crawl the page once, get its cookie, set the cookie in the UserAgent, and crawl it twice more. By doing this, you could get through the welcome page:

```
$response = $browser->get($url);
$cookie_jar->extract_cookies($response);  
$browser->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);
$response = $browser->get($url);
$response = $browser->get($url);
```

This seems to have stopped working for normal LivingSocial pages, but still seems to work for LivinSocialEscapes. E.g.,:

http://livingsocial.com/escapes/148029-cook-islands-hotel-+-airfare

Any tips on how to get past the welcome page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this page only works with a Javascript enabled browser (which `LWP::UserAgent` is not) You could try [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) instead:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get($url);
```

Note that you must have Firefox and the [mozrepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/mozrepl/) extension installed for this module to work.

Comment: Could you perhaps given me a short example of how I would do this with Mechanize? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, so I installed Mechanize::Firefox and cpan tells me MozRepl is up to to date. But when I run the code you supplied I get: Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: Connection refused at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144

Comment: @Vijay: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417904/cant-create-an-instance-of-wwwmechanizefirefox)

Comment: Oh wow - it actually interacts with the Firefox browser! Hmm, I was hoping there was a simpler solution to this (although I really appreciate your replies Eugene) because the production environment that I'm running the crawler on doesn't have Firefox running on it. From what I see in the actual livingsocial page I don't see any relevant javascript code. I believe it's just setting a cookie with a dirty bit for whether you've seen the welcome page.

Comment: Btw Eugene, your solution works (thanks!) I just wish there was something more lightweight. It feels like I'm smashing an egg with a battle axe :)

Comment: @Vijay: I understand you :) But it's definitely a JS issue. Check it yourself: 1) in your browser, remove all cookies for the domain 2) disable JS 3) navigate to the page

Comment: You are correct, indeed Sir. So as a follow up question Eugene, could you suggest how I would get this working in a production environment? I have some servers at Rackspace. Would I just install Firefox on these servers? I see how to install and get MozRepl to work on my desktop linux environment, but I'm not sure how I do it on a remote server.