# WWW:Mechanize:Firefox fails connection

Tags: perl, firefox, mechanize, mozrepl

I am creating a short Perl Script. I am using the [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) module. When I instantiate the object, I believe the module fails to establish a connection with the MozRepl component in Firefox.

My code is as follows:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
```

When I run the code, I get the following error message

```
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: Connection refused at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/MoxRepl/Client.pm line 144'
```

I just installed and updated all relevant software I can think of

1. Perl 5.12.4
2. MozRepl Extension for Firefox
3. CPAN
4. MozRepl
5. WWW::Mechanize
6. WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

I tried adjusting the firewall to open port 4242. Nothing is working. Any ideas?

A similar error code appears in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7417904)

---

**Update**

Ok, Borodin's answer actually fixed 2 problems.

WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new()  only works when

1. The Firefox browser is already open, and
2. After starting Firefox, you follow Borodin's instructions and also start MozRepl

I had expected the Perl script to act like a shell script, and start Firefox for me. This is not the case.

Also, if you hide the menu bar in Firefox, the "Tools" menu is the only menu that is not accessible in the drop-down list that appears on the top left. You have to show the menu bar to access the "Tools" menu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't create an instance of WWW:Mechanize::Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417904/cant-create-an-instance-of-wwwmechanizefirefox)

Answer (score 7):

You need to start the MozRepl add-on in Firefox.

Go to **Tools** / **MozRepl** and click on **Start**

Your program should now work.

Comment: Ok, your answer actually fixed 2 problems.