# Can't get WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to connect

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't create an instance of WWW:Mechanize::Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417904/cant-create-an-instance-of-wwwmechanizefirefox)

I have the following code, taken from the documenation of [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get('http://google.com');

$mech->eval_in_page('alert("Hello Firefox")');
my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
```

and I get this error message:

```
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144
```

Comment: try it with removing `::Firefox` from both lines and removing `eval` line. To use `eval` use `WWW::Scripter` library - see http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.029/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod. Also don't expect *http://google.com* to return you a png as output...

Comment: @Daxim stop saying that last sentence over and over again. Wow.

Comment: @Daxim followed your comment, it is enabled but still same error

Answer (score 2):

Note: if you want a picture that is embedded in a web page then you should establish the URL of the image and download it directly. The `content_as_png` method will return a screenshot of the Firefox window.

Be absolutely certain that `MozRepl` is started and running on Firefox on your machine. Check this by going to `Tools/MozRepl` on Firefox and make sure that the first option is now `Stop`.

Once you know `MozReply` is running, open a command window and enter

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 4242
```

when MozRepl should reply with something like

```
Welcome to MozRepl.
```

and a few lines of advice. (If you are running on a Windows system then you can open a command prompt window by pressing the Windows key and entering `cmd`.)

Then you can finally make certain your connection is working by entering

```
repl.whereAmI()
```

(be careful of the capitalisation). And `MozRepl` will respond with

```
[object ChromeWindow] - Document title: "perl - WWW::Mechanize::Firefox doesn't want to work properly - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox"
```

or similar.

If any of these steps don't work then come back here with your findings.